# How can I use kint within twig template to get the vid value, for example?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, kint

[image: Kint keeps showing DEPTH TOO GREAT]

Also, when I increase max depth within config.default.php every page that has kint used breaks.

Comment: `vid` is the revision ID just fyi and to get it in twig, you'd do `{{  node.getRevisionId }}`. If you are trying to get the node id, you'd do `{{ node.id }}`. If you look at the available methods tab, you'll see the getRevisionId method there.

Comment: **Thanks** a lot.